# Android Alertdialog

Tags: java, android, alertdialog

Boas, estou a desenvolver uma aplicação Android e neste momento, encontrei um problema para o qual não encontro solução, provavelmente estarei a fazer alguma coisa mal, espero que alguém me consiga ajudar. O problema consiste no seguinte: Tenho um alertdialog que abre quando a aplicação é aberta e pede um código. O utilizador introduz o código e a aplicação verifica o codigo na base de dados (mysql) e recebe os dados do utilizador através desse código. Até aqui tudo bem. Mas, quando passo da activity principal para uma segunda activity, repete outra vez o mesmo processo e o alertdialog é aberto novamente a pedir um código. Eu quero que o alertdialog apenas apareça ao iniciar a app. Alguém me consegue ajudar? Abaixo está o código do método OnCreate da Activity principal.

```
//Cria Formulário de pedido
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new 
AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    //Titulo do AlertDialog
    builder.setTitle("Insira o seu código:");

    // Set up the input
    final EditText input = new EditText(MainActivity.this);

    input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | 
InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
    builder.setView(input);

    // Set up the buttons
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            txtstatus.setText("A verificar código . . .");
            //Recebe Código
            at = input.getText().toString();

                //Guarda o Código e o Url
                at = "at=" + at;
                url_nome_user = "/user_nome.php";

                //Verifica e recolhe os dados do Código
                BackgroundTask backgroundTask = new BackgroundTask();
                backgroundTask.execute(url_nome_user);
                txtstatus.setText("A receber Dados associados . . .");
            }
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new 
DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            //Se o Utilizador cancelar
            dialog.cancel();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Falha ao introduzir Código!", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            txtstatus.setText("Falha ao introduzir Código!");
            finish();
        }
    });
    //Desativar Botão Back
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    //cria o AlertDialog
    AlertDialog alerta = builder.create();
    //Exibe
    alerta.show();
```

Agora, na BackgroundTask:

```
class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        //Verifica na API o Código de Acesso
        //Dados User
        nome_user = Conexao.postDados(url_nome_user,at);
        return nome_user;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        //Mostra o Resultado
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        MudardeActivity();
    }
  }

public void MudardeActivity(){
 /* Create an Intent that will start the Menu-Activity. */
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Inicio.class);
intent.putExtra("nome_user", nome_user);

MainActivity.this.finish();
startActivity(intent);

}
```

Alguem me pode ajudar?
Obrigado.

Comment: O primeiro trecho só tem o dialogo (que parece estar em ordem), não tem mais nada neste `onCreate()`? E o método do `onCreate()` de `inicio.class`? Enfim, não tem informação (código) suficiente pra encontrar o que possa estar errado. Você fez o debug passo a passo, pra tentar entender o que esta ocorrendo?

Comment: Após a verificação a Activity Inicio não é chamada? Quando é que "repete outra vez o mesmo processo"?

Comment: Caro Rene Freak, não existe mais código no onCreate. no OnCreate da class Inicio, não existe nada. apenas o layout da activity. o suposto era a aplicação abrir apenas o layout visto que não existe código nenhum.

Comment: Caro Ramaral, a Activity Inicio é chamada, mas ao aparecer, o alertdialog da Activity inicial abre novamente.

Comment: Bem, consegui resolver o problema, e desde já peço desculpa. Eu apenas reescrevi todo o código num novo projeto e está a funcionar :D. Provavelmente mudei alguma definição naquele projeto. Peço-vos desculpa. Obrigado :)